# How to restrict multiple users access same insurance case

Tags: java, session

i need some suggestions in designing application, in my application there will be insurance cases and according to roles users will access the cases and different level of life cycle of the Case.Here i need to restrict users to access same case.If one user is accessing one case with caseid (123) and other user should not able to access same case(123). Please can anyone suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: can you elaborate ".Here i need to restrict users of same accessing same case" because i could not exactly understand you requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of locking. Depending on your specific requirements there are different ways to accomplish this.

For web applications you can use [this algorithm](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/record_locking_in_web_applications.php) which uses a table to store locks and ajax to refresh the locks as long as the user remains on the edit page. The algorithm can be used even if you don't use PHP on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Following is one way of doing  this

1. Make provision in the database (add a column) to indicate that, that particular case  is being accessed.
2. When a user access a case, check the database field if that case is already being accessed, if not update the database field indicating the same.
3. If another user, tries to access the same case, then based on the database field value appropriate response will be send

Its important to note that the transactions mentioned in #2 i.e. database read and update should be ATOMIC.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are planning to implement locking is not a good practice. I am not sure about my sql but if you are using microsoft sql or oracle then the best practice is to implement optimistic lock mechanism. 
The link given below should help you understand better.

www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application